# Keda with kafka scaler won't scale from zero

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, keda

We have multiple K8S clusters and in each cluster we have a kafka cluster.
I want to use keda to scale up and down pods due to topics lag.
The issue is when a new cluster is being created or if we recreate the topics, and the pods are on 0 replicas, the keda does not recognize that there's a new lag. It's happening because it can't identify the consumer group, since it was not created yet.
Is there any solution for that?
Thanks

Comment: Use `kafka-console-consumer --group X` to consume an event and create the group? Or don't automatically deploy with zero replicas? In other words, let it scale down from 1, rather than start at none